# MYSQL query count + distinct for current month

Tags: php, mysql

This mysql table has a transaction history of all users, like this

```
rec_id   |  rec_timestamp         | user_name
1        |  2015-06-06 12:30:00   | userA
2        |  2015-06-07 14:32:30   | userA
3        |  2015-06-08 15:35:12   | userB
4        |  2015-06-09 16:30:22   | userB
5        |  2015-06-10 16:30:22   | userC
6        |  2015-06-11 16:30:22   | userA
7        |  2015-06-12 16:30:22   | userB
8        |  2015-06-13 16:30:22   | userD
9        |  2015-06-14 16:30:22   | userE
10       |  2015-06-14 18:30:22   | userA
11       |  2015-06-15 16:30:22   | userF
12       |  2015-06-16 16:30:22   | userB
```

1. I want to query the mysql to have the 5 usernames that have most records IN THE CURRENT MONTH - sorted descending, like the who has more records, will be first
2. I want to show next to each one of the 5 usernames, how many records has?

Example:

```
Top 5 this month are: 
TOP#1 is UserA with 33 records
TOP#2 is UserD with 22 records
TOP#3 is UserE with 10 records
TOP#4 is UserB with 8 records
TOP#5 is UserF with 4 records
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_name), COUNT(rec_id) 
FROM transactions 
WHERE MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(rec_timestamp) 
SORT BY rec_timestamp DESCENDING LIMIT 5
```

But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to include the year in the `where` clause as well as the month.  Then you need a `GROUP BY` and the right logic:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(recid)
FROM transactions
WHERE YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(update_timestamp) AND
      MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(update_timestamp)
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY COUNT(recid) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Actually, it is better to do the date arithmetic in a "sargable" way -- that means that an index on `update_timestamp` can be used.  The query would look more like this:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(recid)
FROM transactions
WHERE update_timestamp >= date_sub(CURDATE(),  interval day(CURDATE()) - 1 day) AND
      update_timestamp < date_add(date_sub(CURDATE(),  interval day(CURDATE()) - 1 day), interval 1 month)
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY COUNT(recid) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: thanks Gardon, that was really quick, it seems working but the order by recid doesn't work, i changed it to order by count(recid) seems better, do you agree this is ok?

Comment: Thanks Gordan, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```
SELECT MIN(user_name), COUNT(rec_id)
FROM tran_history
WHERE rec_timestamp >= '2015-06-01' AND rec_timestamp < '2015-07-01' 
GROUP BY user_name
ORDER BY COUNT(rec_id) DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

MIN(user_name) is not essential for MySQL but good practice for SQL variants such as SQL Server that don't like mixing of non-aggregated fields in GROUP BY statements.